# Collision between kinematic bodies in Bullet Physics

Tags: collision-detection, collision, bulletphysics, bullet, kinematics

I'm working with Bullet Physics Engine.
My created world is based on:

- Static Object --> Ground
- Dinamic Object --> Is going to be moved by other objects.
- 2 Kinematic objects --> They are going to move the dinamic one. I need to control them from outside, so that I need kinematic objects.

The collision between each kinematic and the dinamic works as expected.

However, when one kinematic collide with the other, it oversteps and I need them to collide and "react" to that collision (like a Dinamic body)

I've been looking for an answer but I have not found any solution.
What can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to control them from outside, so that I need kinematic objects

This assertion isn't entirely accurate. Dynamic objects can also be controlled.

> However, when one kinematic collide with the other, it oversteps and I need them to collide and "react" to that collision (like a Dinamic body)

Kinematic bodies don't collide/react with each other within the engine. One could reproduce that code externally to make them react but lets not go there. If you have to have those bodies that you've created as kinematic bodies react with other bodies that are also kinematic, then I suggest using dynamic bodies instead.

> What can I do?

Instead of creating those bodies as kinematic bodies:

1. Create them as dynamic bodies; and
2. **use a force/impulse-based [constraint mechanism](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Constraints) to "control" them**.

Comment: Well, I change the method of the bodies from setLinealVelocity() to ApplyCentralImpulse and everything works fine. Thanks a lot, marked as solution. I also changed kinematic to dynamics.